# how to run same android app with different name in one device?

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0

I build a two apk from same source code . both have Different  name,icon background  .i changed only UI and app name tow app have same package,
my problem is I can't install this both app on same device .when I try to install facing error message .

How I can run this two application (build from same source just change name and icon) on same device .? what are the values I should change in application to run this app separately .?

Kindly Give me a hand with this

Comment: Learn about flavors in android

Comment: You need to use `Flavors` in `Android Studio`.

Comment: You need to change name & packagename both.

Comment: @Arjun Thank you for your reply

Comment: @Arjun i am using google map api inside my code .does it affect map api. if i change package name.?

Comment: Yes, it will effect. You need to create another map key when you change your package name,

Comment: Package name have to be different if you want to install a application twice as android does not support a process to be created with the same id which is its package name.

Comment: Try [Flavors in Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/12/leveraging-product-flavors-in-android.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change package name to make Android System detect your 2nd app as different from first. App name doesn't matter.

Comment: i am using google Map API in side my code .if i change packge name does it affect MAP API.?

Comment: Yes. You would need the key according to your package name.

Answer (score 1):

Use `productFlavors` in your `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            applicationId "com.company.app.dev" // package name for dev flavor
        }
        beta {
            applicationId "com.company.app.beta" // package name for beta 
        }
        production {
            applicationId "com.company.app" // package name for production 
        }
    }
}
```

All your files can still be in your `src/main` dir. Flavor specific changes can be placed in `src/beta` etc.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to **change the name and the package name** of your second instance of the application.